# p4 add with apostrophes in the filename

Tags: continuous-integration, special-characters, perforce

We have a process that I'm trying to automate in which I have to check generated output files into perforce. I understand this is far from ideal, but it's not something I can really get around. In order to ensure all generated files get into perforce I have to check an entire directory into perforce. According to perforce's documentation [in their knowledge base](http://kb.perforce.com/article/2/working-disconnected-from-the-perforce-server) there's a rather goofy looking but valid command you can run:

```
dir /s /b /a-d | p4 -x - add
```

Everything appears at first to run fine when you execute this, for each filename with an apostrophe (single quote?) I get a message saying

> *filename* - missing, assuming text.

This despite the fact that my list of files to add was generated by dir. In otherwords, it should be impossible (barring perhaps another process interfering) for one of these files to be missing since it is *the list of files in the dir*.

If I try to submit the resulting changelist, submission fails when it cannot find the missing file(s). I've tried a couple of longshot things like redirecting the dir output into a file and then reading the arguments for add from that file, but it worked just the same.

Perhaps the craziest part of all of this is that I've discovered is that

```
p4 add Jim's_File.txt
```

works if I use tab complete, but fails if I type, paste, or pipe the name. I have no clue how to work around this behavior, but would really love some ideas.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? I can't write better questions if I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me:

Created a file named a'file.txt

```
c:\some_path>p4 add a'file.txt
//source/path-in-depot/a'file.txt#1 - opened for add
```

Perhaps you should mention your Perforce version and operating system.

Generally speaking, it's best to wrap each filename in quotes (`"a'file.txt"`) or, in Windows shell, use the `^` symbol to escape any characters that have special meaning.

Comment: Interesting. I did already try quoting the filename and it made no difference. I will perform a for more tests and if they don't work I'll post various version information.

Comment: Okay, we have determined that the "apostrophe" is not actually an apostrophe. Looking closely in windows explorer at the file name and my own hand-made version of "a'file.txt" reveals my problem file has a strange piece of punctuation that the doc writers - or one of the doc tools - somehow put there. In many fonts it looks like an apostrophe, and copy pasting even treats it as such, but I guess the treatment is inconsistent and leads to my problem. Thanks for providing a second set of data to work with!

Answer (score 0):

In the 2012.1 release there's a new `p4 reconcile` command that makes the goofy `dir | p4 add` trick unnecessary. `p4 reconcile` will handle apostrophes, along with other difficult-to-quote strings, in filenames.

The 2012.1 server is still in beta, I think. That may be the reason it's not mentioned in the [knowledge base article](http://kb.perforce.com/article/2/working-disconnected-from-the-perforce-server).

Comment: That sounds rather nice. I'm afraid I won't be able to get them to upgrade perforce to a beta release just for me, but I look forward to the day we have it! :)